# Laravel 5.8 Validation Race Condition

Tags: laravel, validation, request, race-condition, laravel-5.8

I have this validation rule on `POST` request method inside a controller:

```php
class CreateOrderController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'store_id' => $request->order_type === OrdersTypeConstants::P2P  ? "" : "required|" . 'exists:stores,id',
            'p2p_type' => [Rule::in([OrdersTypeConstants::P2PCOURIER, OrdersTypeConstants::P2PPURCHASE])],
            'items' => 'required_if:p2p_type,'.OrdersTypeConstants::P2PPURCHASE.'|array',
            'items.*.id' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'items.*.quantity' => 'nullable|integer|min:1',
            'items.*.adjustment' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'items.*.image' => 'nullable|string',
            'items.*.addons' => 'array',
            'items.*.reward_applied' => 'boolean',
            'items.*.replacement_strategy.type' => [
                'string',
                Rule::in([ItemReplacementStrategyConstants::REMOVE,ItemReplacementStrategyConstants::BEST_MATCH, ItemReplacementStrategyConstants::SPECIFIC])
            ],
            'items.*.replacement_strategy.quantity' => 'integer|min:1',
            'items.*.replacement_strategy.item_id' => 'numeric',
            'address_id' => 'exists:addresses,id,user_id,' . $client_id,
            'address_id_p1' => 'exists:addresses,id,user_id,' . $client_id,
            'use_cash_deposit' => 'boolean',
        ]);
```

Sometime it returns `The store id field is required` even if it is actually being **sent** as you can see here in the error log:
[image]

It is only happening randomly -not consistently- only on production environment, reported only on firebase.

Why could that be happening?

Comment: what inside your validate() ? i didnt see you using Request::validate() or Validator::make()

Comment: @AlzafanChristian Controllers have a `validate` method, the base Controller in your application uses the `ValidatesRequest` trait

Comment: @lagbox yeah sorry, totally forgot contorller in app/Http/Controllers/Controller has ValidatesRequests, i didnt always extends that Controller

Comment: thanks @lagbox I updated the code snippet context to show the class

Comment: If you log $request->all() just before the validator, is the value present there? I can't see why it wouldn't be, but just to be sure.

Comment: it is only happening randomly -not consistently- only on production environment, reported only on firebase @PatricNox

Comment: That is probably useful information to include within the original post.

Comment: I think $request->order_type may or may not exist when it runs the validation rule which explains the inconsistency. look into require if https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: As @Cameron pointed it seems to be related to order_type is present or not. Can you update the question and show if order_type is present and if is equals or not to `OrdersTypeConstants::P2P`?

Comment: Please don't make validation in the controller class, create the FormRequest file for following the SOLID principle. Code is terrible to watch & read.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me several times. All the times the problem was an invalid JSON.
You can validate yours [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

When Laravel encounters an invalid JSON, it just ignores it, and assumes the payload is empty.

The fact that it gives you a validation error on `store_id is required` is not a coincidence. Your framework is setup to stop on first failed rule, and this rule just happens to be `store_id => 'required'`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if request()->all() has any data (your json could be invalid)